# how to make conky true transparent?

Tags: 17.10, conky

There is no true transparency. how can i fix it?

```
# By Jesse_Avalos , See me on Eye Candy Linux_  on Google +
#Modified by http://www.NoobsLab.com

background yes
use_xft yes
xftfont Roboto:size=9
xftalpha 0.8
update_interval 1
total_run_times 0
own_window yes
own_window_transparent yes
##############################################
# Compositing tips:
# Conky can play strangely when used with
# different compositors. I have found the
# following to work well, but your mileage
# may vary. Comment/uncomment to suit.
##############################################
## no compositor
own_window_type conky
own_window_argb_visual yes

## xcompmgr
#own_window_type conky
#own_window_argb_visual yes

## cairo-compmgr
own_window_type conky
own_window_argb_visual no
##############################################
own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager
double_buffer yes
draw_shades no
draw_outline no
draw_borders no
draw_graph_borders no
stippled_borders 0
border_margin 5
border_width 1
default_color 1C1C1C
default_shade_color 000000
default_outline_color 000000
alignment top_right
minimum_size 600 600
maximum_width 900
gap_x 505
gap_y 70
alignment top_right
no_buffers yes
uppercase no
cpu_avg_samples 2
net_avg_samples 2
short_units yes
text_buffer_size 2048
use_spacer none
override_utf8_locale yes
color1 212021
color2 E8E1E6
color3 E82A2A
own_window_argb_value 0
own_window_colour 000000
TEXT
${goto 245}${voffset 25}${font GeosansLight:size=25} Today
${goto 124}${voffset -}${font GeosansLight:light:size=70}${time %I:%M}${image .conky/blackline.png -p 350,26 -s 10x189}
${offset 150}${voffset -55}${font GeosansLight:size=17}${time %A, %d %B}
${offset 380}${voffset -177}${font GeosansLight:size=25}Systems${font GeosansLight:size=22}
${offset 400}${voffset 5}${font GeosansLight:size=15}$acpitemp'C
${offset 400}${voffset 10}${cpu cpu0}% / 100%
${offset 400}${voffset 4}$memfree / $memmax${font GeosansLight:size=15}
${offset 400}${voffset 5}${if_up wlp6s0}${upspeed wlp6s0} kb/s / ${totalup wlp6s0}${endif}${if_up eth0}${upspeed eth0} kb/s / ${totalup eth0}${endif}${if_up ppp0}${upspeed ppp0} kb/s / ${totalup ppp0}${endif}
${offset 400}${voffset 5}${if_up wlp6s0}${downspeed wlp6s0} kb/s / ${totaldown wlp6s0}${endif}${if_up eth0}${downspeed eth0} kb/s / ${totaldown eth0}${endif}${if_up ppp0}${downspeed ppp0} kb/s / ${totaldown ppp0}${endif}

${goto 373}${voffset -162}${font Dingytwo:size=17}M$font 
${goto 373}${voffset 7}${font Dingytwo:size=17}7$font 
${goto 373}${voffset 1}${font Dingytwo:size=17}O$font 
${goto 373}${voffset 1}${font Dingytwo:size=17}5$font 
${goto 373}${voffset 1}${font Dingytwo:size=17}4$font
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post your `conky` code in your question?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find this section:

```
## no compositor
own_window_type conky
own_window_argb_visual yes

## xcompmgr
#own_window_type conky
#own_window_argb_visual yes

## cairo-compmgr
own_window_type conky
own_window_argb_visual no
```

Copy this code over top of the section:

```
## no compositor
#own_window_type conky
#own_window_argb_visual yes

## xcompmgr
own_window_type conky
own_window_argb_visual yes

## cairo-compmgr
#own_window_type conky
#own_window_argb_visual no
```